# Android: Instagram fotos de um determinado usuário

Tags: android, instagram-api

Cenário:

No meu aplicativo quero mostrar as fotos de um usuário. Estou autenticando, tenho acesso ao token e consigo logar com usuário e senha mas depois de logar ele diz que não tenho permissão para abrir essa página.

Código:

PhotosActivity.java

```
public static final String CLIENT_ID = "seu_id";
public static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "seu_secret";
public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "callback";
String url ="https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize?" +"response_type=token" + "&redirect_uri=" + CALLBACK_URL+"&scope=basic"+"&client_id=" + CLIENT_ID ;

WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo_activity);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView2);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            String fragment = "#access_token=";
            int start = url.indexOf(fragment);
            if (start > -1) {

                // You can use the accessToken for api calls now.
                String accessToken = url.substring(start + fragment.length(), url.length());

                Log.v(TAG, "OAuth complete, token: [" + accessToken + "].");
                Log.i(TAG, "" +accessToken);
Toast.makeText(PhotosActivity.this, "Token: " + accessToken, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    webview.loadUrl(url);

}
```

Comment: A `CALLBACK_URL` é o link de uma página de seu servidor que termina o processo do OAuth obtendo o token correto? Ou está usando uma url fake só para extrair o token da url? Outra dúvida, cadastrou essa `CALLBACK_URL` em sua conta de desenvolvedor do Instagram?

Comment: Eu estou usando uma URL fake e cadastrei essa URL lá na conta de desenvolvedor do Instagram sim. 
O erro que estou recebendo é `{"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "error_message": "Implicit authentication is disabled"}` Na verdade eu gostaria de exibir as fotos publicas de um user sem aparecer essa tela de login do Instagram.

Comment: Ah, entendi... Você esta usando o Fluxo Implícito, não sabia que existia essa forma de autenticação. Dê uma olhada no painel de desenvolvedor do Instagram, se a checkbox de `Disable implicit OAuth` está desmarcada para seu aplicativo.

Comment: Então, logo após que postei a resposta da sua pergunta, fui lá e desmarquei essa opção e funcionou. Mas engraçado que estou testando no AVD e em um tablet da Samsung. No AVD está "correto", mas no tablet meu App fecha.

Comment: Coloque o cabo USB e verifique no LogCat qual foi a exceção que ocorreu.

Comment: Você sabe como faço para carregar as fotos de um determinado usuário do Instagram sem precisar fazer essa autenticação, ou melhor, que essa autenticação rode em background sem ter que digitar user/senha?

Comment: Só da pra fazer isso se o perfil for público (https://help.instagram.com/116024195217477/). Eu usava o método http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent, o `access_token` no caso era o meu API_KEY.

Comment: Sim, a ideia é apenas para perfil público. Teria como você exemplificar como usa esse método?

Comment: Ok, vou pegar um código que usei com o mesmo propósito e crio uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Tive a mesma necessidade que você, acessar as imagens de um perfil público no Instagram no Aplicativo Android.

Mas uma coisa que fiz de diferente, foi criar um `WebService` que de tempos em tempos consulta a API de mídias e atualiza o banco de dados. Porém o núcleo do acesso deve ser bem parecido.

Fiz isso porque não sei se vale a pena deixar o `Client ID` no aplicativo, por questões de segurança, alguém pode espionar as requisições e pegar o `Client ID` que seu aplicativo esta usando, podendo fazer com que esse `Client ID` fique inválido.

O código é um pouco mais complexo, porque eu tentei normalizar o consumo de várias API's de redes sociais, vou colocar apenas a parte específica do Instagram.

Para montar a URI de acesso ao `WebService` do instagram eu fiz:

```
public String getUri(String instagramUserId, String token, int amount) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder uri = new StringBuilder("https://api.instagram.com/v1");

    // instagramUserId é uma variável local com o ID do usuário de perfil público
    // Pode ser obtido nesse site: http://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id
    // token é o Client ID do aplicativo
    // amount é a quantidade de registros que devem ser retornadas

     uri.append("/users/").append(instagramUserId)
        .append("/media/recent?client_id=").append(URLEncoder.encode(token, "UTF-8"))
        .append("&count=").append(Integer.toString(amount));

    return uri.toString();
}
```

Com essa URI eu fiz um `HttpRequest` para o endpoint do Instagram, como abaixo:

```
@Override
public List<JSONObject> fetchInstagram(String instagramUserId, String token, int amount) {
    try {
        String uri = getUri(instagramUserId, token, amount);

        if(uri == null) {
            return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        }

        // Inicializa um cliente Http
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

        // Especifica o método a ser executado, GET como especificado pela documentacao do Instagram
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(uri);

        // Definindo o Charset da resposta, a fim de evitar problemas com encoding
        // Definindo que o cliente aceita codificação gzip, para reduzir o gasto de banda do dispositivo.
        get.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        get.addHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");

        System.out.println("Making request to " + uri);

        // Executa a requisicao e espera pela resposta
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);

        // Se o Instagram nao respondeu com codigo 200 (OK), entao loga o erro
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            return null;
        }

        // Extrai a resposta em formato String
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        // Retorna a lista de registros de midia do usuario
        return parseResponse(responseString);
    } catch (MalformedURLException | ProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

// Aqui poderia ser retornado o próprio JSONArray com os registros
public List<JSONObject> parseResponse(String response) {
    // Transforma a resposta String em JSON, para poder manipular
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

    // Atributo do JSON que contem a lista de registros obtidos do usuario
    JSONArray registros = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("data");
    List<JSONObject> objetos = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

    for(int i = 0; i < registros.length(); ++i) {
        JSONObject o = registros.getJSONObject(i);

        // Faz uma logica com o registro em si, filtragem, normalizacao, ou outro qualquer

        objetos.add(o);
    }

    return registros;
}
```

Para usar, basta fazer:

```
public void callInstagram() {
    String token = "SEU_CLIENT_D";
    String instagramUserId = "USER_ID";

    int amount = 100;

    List<JSONObject> registros = fetchInstagram(instagramUserId, token, amount);

    // Processa os registros, levando em conta o tipo e as resolucoes das midias.
}
```

Nessa solução acabei usando a API do `HttpComponents` do Apache (para usar a classe HttpClient, HttpGet e HttpClientBuilder), que pode ser obtida nesse endereço: http://hc.apache.org/. Existe a migração para Android neste endereço: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html.

Um exemplo de resposta JSON do Instagram é:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "comments": {
            "data": [],
            "count": 0
        },
        "caption": {
            "created_time": "1296710352",
            "text": "Inside le truc #foodtruck",
            "from": {
                "username": "kevin",
                "full_name": "Kevin Systrom",
                "type": "user",
                "id": "3"
            },
            "id": "26621408"
        },
        "likes": {
            "count": 15,
            "data": [{
                "username": "mikeyk",
                "full_name": "Mike Krieger",
                "id": "4",
                "profile_picture": "..."
            }, {...subset of likers...}]
        },
        "link": "http://instagr.am/p/BWrVZ/",
        "user": {
            "username": "kevin",
            "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1295574122.jpg",
            "id": "3"
        },
        "created_time": "1296710327",
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2011/02/02/6ea7baea55774c5e81e7e3e1f6e791a7_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "type": "image",
        "users_in_photo": [],
        "filter": "Earlybird",
        "tags": ["foodtruck"],
        "id": "22721881",
        "location": {
            "latitude": 37.778720183610183,
            "longitude": -122.3962783813477,
            "id": "520640",
            "street_address": "",
            "name": "Le Truc"
        }
    },
    {
        "videos": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_102.mp4",
                "width": 480,
                "height": 480
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_101.mp4",
                "width": 640,
                "height": 640
            },
        "comments": {
            "data": [{
                "created_time": "1279332030",
                "text": "Love the sign here",
                "from": {
                    "username": "mikeyk",
                    "full_name": "Mikey Krieger",
                    "id": "4",
                    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1242695_75sq_1293915800.jpg"
                },
                "id": "8"
            },
            {
                "created_time": "1279341004",
                "text": "Chilako taco",
                "from": {
                    "username": "kevin",
                    "full_name": "Kevin S",
                    "id": "3",
                    "profile_picture": "..."
                },
                "id": "3"
            }],
            "count": 2
        },
        "caption": null,
        "likes": {
            "count": 1,
            "data": [{
                "username": "mikeyk",
                "full_name": "Mikeyk",
                "id": "4",
                "profile_picture": "..."
            }]
        },
        "link": "http://instagr.am/p/D/",
        "created_time": "1279340983",
        "images": {
            "low_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_6.jpg",
                "width": 306,
                "height": 306
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_5.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "standard_resolution": {
                "url": "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/11f75f1cd9cc11e2a0fd22000aa8039a_7.jpg",
                "width": 612,
                "height": 612
            }
        },
        "type": "video",
        "users_in_photo": null,
        "filter": "Vesper",
        "tags": [],
        "id": "363839373298",
        "user": {
            "username": "kevin",
            "full_name": "Kevin S",
            "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_3_75sq_1295574122.jpg",
            "id": "3"
        },
        "location": null
    },
   ]
}
```

Você vai precisar ver quais campos de cada objeto que compõem a resposta é necessário, e levar em consideração que para alguns tipos de mídia (imagem nesse caso), ele fornece várias resoluções, que podem ser usadas em dispositivos diferentes (tablets ou smartphone).

Comment: A sua solução parece ser muito boa. Porém para quem está iniciando, que é meu caso, não dá para entender muito bem. Seria interessante deixar mais claro sua solução para que outras pessoas, tanto com mais experiência ou pouca experiência entendessem melhor.

Comment: Ok, vou tentar da uma simplificada e colocar mais comentários.

Comment: Pronto @fricks, dei uma atualizada. Simplifiquei, comentei algumas partes, coloquei um exemplo de uso dos métodos e coloquei uma referência para a biblioteca que eu usei nesse exemplo.

Comment: Ainda não tive sucesso com isso @Wakim!

Comment: @fricks, tente especificar melhor sua dúvida que eu tento detalhar mais.

Comment: Eu não sei como organizar seu código dentro do meu PhotosActivity e não entendi nada sobre a API do HttpComponents que você comentou pois nunca usei.